# uwp media element seekbar pointer hover frame show

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, hover, media

I want to implement a specific feature on my media element, that when user hovers over the seekbar then a tooltip show popup to show a thumbnail like frame of the video playing of that specific position (where the mouse pointer is) and when pointer moves over the seekbar the frame should be changing with it.

I know it will require some sort of binding. How can I achieve this? I've looked through template of media element and I saw a tooltip on the seekbar seeker, but I don't know if it's functional or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to implement a specific feature on my media element, that when user hovers over the seekbar then a tooltip show popup to show a thumbnail like frame of the video playing

Currently, there is no such api to respond pointer hover gesture.

You could use [`MediaPlayerElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaplayerelement) and implement [`ThumbnailRequested`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediatransportcontrols#events_) event in your [`MediaTransportControls`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediatransportcontrols#definition). It occurs whenever the app needs to display a thumbnail adjacent to the seek bar when the user performs a seek operation.

```
<MediaPlayerElement x:Name="Player"
       MaxWidth="400"
       AutoPlay="False"
       AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"  >
     <MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
         <MediaTransportControls IsZoomButtonVisible="False" IsZoomEnabled="False"
                         IsPlaybackRateButtonVisible="True"
                                 IsPlaybackRateEnabled="True" 
                                 ThumbnailRequested="ControlsThumbnailRequested" 
                                 IsSeekEnabled="True" />
     </MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
</MediaPlayerElement>
```

In the code behind please call [`SetThumbnailImage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.mediatransportcontrolsthumbnailrequestedeventargs#methods_) method with args for setting thumbnail image.

```
private async void ControlsThumbnailRequested(MediaTransportControls sender, MediaTransportControlsThumbnailRequestedEventArgs args)
{


}
```

Comment: it is helpful but it is not what I was looking for, If there isnt an api for this , Microsoft should make one, because I cant see any other way this can be done, without a proper API

Comment: If you do want this feature, you are welcome to ask on [UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform) .